# How can we increase the subnet size in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

In Azure, we keep running into "ip address capacity" issues from time to time. Is there a way to increase the subnet size *without* affecting the servers that are already provisioned in that subnet ?

Creating a new subnet is always an option. But then we have to deal with the hassle of moving servers from the old subnet to the new subnet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once a subnet has resources in it, the subnet cannot be resized.

[Change subnet settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-manage-subnet#change-subnet-settings)

Comment: Is this possible on other clouds like GCP or AWS ?

Comment: AWS: no. Google Cloud: resize larger only: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-vpc#expand-subnet

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would add an additional subnet to grow the vnet as the proper course of action. Then you would have to adjust your workloads to use that new subnet size you have added.